# How to create an ISO 8859-15 (instead of default UTF-8) encoded text file on Linux using QTextStream?

Tags: c++, qt, character-encoding, qtextstream

The function below is something I have created in a unit test for a Qt project I'm working on.

It creates a file (empty or filled) that is then opened in various use cases, processed and the outcome evaluated. One special use case I have identified is that the encoding actually does affect my application so I decided to cover non-UTF-8 files too (as far as this is possible).

```
void TestCsvParserOperators::createCsvFile(QString& path, CsvType type, bool utf8)
{
    path = "test_data.txt";

    QFile csv(path);
    // Make sure both reading and writing access is possible. Also turn on truncation to replace any existing files
    QVERIFY(csv.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text) == true);

    QTextStream csvStream(&csv);

    // Set encoding
    if (utf8)
    {
        csvStream.setCodec("UTF-8");
    }
    else
    {
        csvStream.setCodec("ISO 8859-15");
        csvStream.setGenerateByteOrderMark(false);
    }

    switch(type)
    {
    case EMPTY:     // File doesn't contain any data
        break;
    case INVALID:   // File contains data that is not supported
        csvStream << "abc" << '\n';
        break;
    case VALID:
    {
        // ...
        break;
    }
    }

    csv.close();
}
```

While the project runs on **Linux** the data is exported as a **plain text file** on **Windows** (and possibly edited with **Notepad**) and used by my application as it is. I discovered that it is encoded not as UTF-8 but as ISO 8859-15. This led to a bunch of problems including incorrectly processed characters etc.

The actual part in my application that is tested is

```
// ...

QTextStream in(&csvFile);
if (in.codec() != QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"))
{
    LOG(WARNING) << this->sTag << "Expecting CSV file with UTF-8 encoding. Found " << QString(in.codec()->name()) << ". Will attempt to convert to supported encoding";

    // Handle encoding
    // ...
}

// ...
```

Regardless of the combination of values for `type` and `utf8` I always get my test text file. However the encoding remains **UTF-8** regardless of the `utf8` flag.

Calling `file` on the CSV file with the actual data (shipped by the client) returns

```
../trunk/resources/data.txt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```

while doing the same on `test_data.txt` gives me

```
../../build/test-bin/test_data.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

I've read somewhere that if I want to use some encoding other than UTF-8 I have to work with `QByteArray`. However I am unable to verify this in the Qt documentation. I've also read that setting the `BOM` should do the trick but I tried with both enabling and disabling its generation without any luck.

I've already written a small bash script which converts the encoding to UTF-8 (given that the input file is ISO 8859) but I'd like to

- have this integrated in my actual application
- not being forced to take care of this every single time
- have at least some basic test coverage for the encoding that the client uses

Any ideas how to achieve this?

---

**UPDATE:** I replaced the content I'm writing to the text file as

```
csvStream << QString("...").toLatin1() << ...;
```

and now I get

```
../../build/test-bin/test_data.txt: ASCII text
```

which is still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: `void QTextStream::setCodec` , If QTextStream operates on a string, this function does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this is what I do:

```
QTextCodec *codec1 = QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-15");
QByteArray csvStreambyteArray = " .... "; // from your file
QString csvStreamString = codec1->toUnicode(csvStreambyteArray);
csvStream << csvStreamString ;
```